# Redirect a website to another website when requested from a tab or mobile?

Tags: url-rewriting

As i have hosted so many flash games on my website and i am planning
to do some android games and the real question is i want my flash
games website requested from any mobile or tab should be redirected to
google play store. A simple example for this is when i am surfing i
have observed this technique in this website called
`www.freeonlinegames.com`

Please open this link in any tab or mobile. You will notice. Can
anyone give me any clue for this. I have a idea like we can do this
with some htaccess trick. But i need more working demo for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# detect mobile agents
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} "text\/vnd\.wap\.wml|application\/vnd\.wap\.xhtml\+xml" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile|windows ce|epoc|opera" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "blackberry|ericsson,|panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|danger|palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,|alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\.|wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://play.google.com/ [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava...You are really a great guy in solving any kind of .htaccess doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use something like [PHP-mobile-detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/). Small example:

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

if($detect->isMobile() || $detect->isTablet()){
    header('Location: mobile_version/index.php');
    exit;
}
```